# singular or plural : doctor's bills?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, possessives

Should I use "doctor's bills" or "doctors' bills" in the following?

> All the money went on **doctor’s bills**.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85597/discussion-on-question-by-apollyon-singular-or-plural-doctors-bills).

Comment: How many doctors?

Comment: Well, my answer seems to have been ignored. Yet, I answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are four scenarios, where three and four are semantically equivalent:

- All my money went to a doctor's bills. [one doctor, many bills from  him]
- All my money went to a doctor's bill. [one doctor sending an expensive bill]
- All my money went to doctors' bills. [generic]
- All my money went to doctor bills. [generic]

Nota bene: If there is one doctor and many bills, the determiner "a" must be used, as in Line One.

The last one is the use of a noun as adjective. Sentence three and four can express the idea of more than one doctor and more than one bill.

You can use went on, but I prefer went to.

Comment: How about "doctor's bills" with no article in the OP?

Comment: No, the OP has the singular "doctor's," whereas your third line has the plural "doctors'."

Comment: No. line one is still different. Your line One example has an article, whereas the "doctor's" has none.

Comment: That's RIGHT. Yours is wrong: if there is ***one*** doctor and ***many*** bills, it's: All my money went on or to ***a doctor's bills***.  I am repeating what I said.

Comment: How about "All the funding has been paid for driver's licenses"? Here, "driver's" is in the singular and "licenses" in the plural.

Comment: @Apollyon You are now playing games. Drivers' licenses are not funded. You are either interested or not interested in the four cases. If I were  you, I would learn that idea before trying to catch out a person who is trying to help you. But, it's the same deal:  **The organization's funding all went to paying for drivers' licenses." (AmE) And: driving licenses, BrE.